# Link to Firefox bookmarks folder by hyperlink in Windows 7?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, browser-tabs

I often search for a certain term in the internet and then end up with a lot of open tabs in Firefox 17 (Windows 7) containing interesting information.

For accessing this information later, I can store all the tabs into a bookmarks folder.
I'm now searching for a way to open all those bookmarks in tabs in Firefox from an external application (e. g. Emacs or MS Office 2007), so I wonder:

is there a hyperlink or command, which I can launch from within an external application like `Emacs` or `MS Word`  which lets Firefox open all bookmarks in a certain bookmarks-(sub-)folder in tabs?

*Example:*

I have saved 10 tabs in the bookmarks folder "my10SearchResults" in Firefox.
Now, some day later, I want Firefox to open all those 10 bookmarks in tabs and I do **not** want to open Firefox, click through the bookmarks hierarchy, **but** I want to launch that "open all tabs of bookmarks folder "my10searchresults" from within another application.

One idea of mine: maybe there is a way to use a hyperlink like "http://firefox:bookmarks:path:my10searchresults" (sorry for the stupid example!) which I could paste into another application to achieve that.

Comment: You didn't explain this well. What do you want to open and from where? If you want to open all the bookmarks within a folder within Firefox, each having a new tab, then Ctrl+Click on the folder.

Comment: I hope my edit made clearer what I want.